# Django: how to add "set & save" method to Model class?

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to make `set()` method for Django's Model class that's will set values to specified fields and then save object, so it can be called like this:

```
object.set(field_1 = 0, field_2 = 1)
```

Instead of this:

```
object.field_1 = 0
object.field_2 = 1
object.save()
```

Comment: I think it can be done via `setattr(self, arg, value)`, but I don't know how to extract arguments and their values from `kwargs`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is implementation of `set()` method via proxy class:

```
class foo(models.Model)
  ...

class foo_proxy(foo)
  class Meta:
    proxy = True

  def set(self, **kwargs):
    for arg, val in kwargs.items():
      setattr(self, arg, val)
    self.save()
```

And here via abstract class:

```
class model(models.Model)
  class Meta:
    abstract = True

  def set(self, **kwargs):
    for arg, val in kwargs.items():
      setattr(self, arg, val)
    self.save()

class foo(model)
  ...
```